# How do I remove this round metal insert in an old wardrobe?

Tags: closet, wardrobe

[image: photo of metal insert in situ]

It's some kind of screw/insert of an old wardrobe/closet.

Comment: I think it is to hold a rod to hang clothes.  I think it is an insert more than a screw in type so if it really needs to be removed, then probably need to pop it out.  Can probably just cover it over and paint if it bothers you or just leave it.

Comment: I want to take apart the wardrobe and i have no idea how it work or how to even remove it the inside move in a cycle motion

Comment: It is hard to tell from that picture exactly where this is.  It does not look to be holding the wardrobe together, just in a panel.  Maybe more pictures showing it's use/location will help.  Placing a large screwdriver or similar tool in that slot and either turning or plying will remove it.

Comment: I second both of  @crip659 comments

Comment: I think I've seen these screw in…  Could there be a screw thread on the outside of it?  (I can't tell from the picture.)

Answer (score 7):

It's a **camlock**. Standard knockdown/flatpack furniture fastener (Ikea, *et al*) though of a slightly different design than many.

It pulls straight out at you in this picture, which may be a little difficult judging by the fuzz on the edge of the hole, but it's not locked into its mating fastener, so it's free to come out (they often fall out when not connected, but again, the fuzz on the hole suggests *not this one.*)

**There's no need to remove it for disassembly.** If it was locked into its mating part, (which would poke into it from the hole on the left side) you'd need to release it, but that's already been done and the mating part is not even there.

*It's possible that someone used glue when assembling the flatpack - that would make it difficult to impossible to disassemble without damage.*

Comment: Thanks a lot i will see what i can do

Answer (score 3):

The inside appears to turn clockwise to lock. The whole assembly looks like it's been glued in, so removing it will most likely take out some of the surrounding material . Only way to extract it is with a smallish flat lever - bent at its tip, and work as gently as you can around until it (hopefully) pops out. But that's nowhere near guaranteed. A heat gun may help soften up the glue before starting. And you'll be left with a mess that'll need even more glue to re-fit.

Comment: Thanks a lot i was really confused with how its even staying together and how to remove it. Its pretty old went through a lot and the previous owners probably just glued everything to keep it all together. Now i will see how i will do it so i wont damage it a lot